# Formatting of pandas dataframe and ranking per section rather than whole df

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have a scraper for a sports site. All runs well but I need help in outputting data. A snippet of my current code is:

```
for item in course_racecard:

  for link in a_tag:

        race_link = (times.find_previous('a')['href'])
        full_url = urljoin(url, race_link)


      for item in entries:

        for horse_info in item.find_all(class_='horse_extended'):

                li = item.find_all("li")

                trainer = li[0].text.strip()

                jockey = li[1].text.strip()

                data.append({
                    "Date": date,
                    "Course": race_course,
                    "Times": times.text,
                    #"URL": full_url,
                    "Title": race_title_simple,
                    "Distance": distance,
                    "Runners": number_of_runners,
                    "Age Group": age_group,
                    "Class": race_class_simple,
                    "Going": going,
                    "Surface": surface,
                    "Horse": horse_name,
                    "Trainer": trainer,
                    "Jockey": jockey,
                    "Age": age_simple,
                    "Weight": weight,
                    "Official Rating": rating_simple,
                    "Form": simple_horse_form,
                    "Exchange Back Odds": odds_int,
                    "weight in stone": weight_in_stone,
                    "Timeform Favourites": "",
                })

                df = pd.DataFrame(data)

                df['Going'] = df['Going'].str.replace('Going: ', '')

                df['Surface'] = df['Surface'].str.replace('Surface: ', '')

                df['Distance'] = df['Distance'].str.replace('Distance:  ', '')

                df['Age Group'] = df['Age Group'].str.replace('Age:  ', '')

                df['Runners'] = df['Runners'].str.replace('Runners:  ', '')

                df['Odds Ranking'] = df['Exchange Back Odds'].rank(ascending=False)

                df['Official Rating Ranking'] = df['Official Rating'].rank(ascending=True)

                df['Weight Ranking'] = df['weight in stone'].rank(ascending=True)
```

This whole scraper takes all of the days racing from multiple URLS and outputs to a CSV that looks like this:

[CSV current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn8Ir.png)

However I would like an output like this:

[CSV desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGrIL.png)

The difference being is that after each race I would like a spare line and then to repeat the column / df headers.

Also in my coding you will see that I rank some of the rows and I want to do this per race. The coding works fine when it was just running on one race at a time but now that it is importing a large number of races it is ranking all of the data from all of the rows rather than just per race (for example the horse with the lowest odds having the highest rank is supposed to be per race but it is now doing it across all races).

This is what it was like with an individual race:

[Ranking on individual race](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhpuu.png)

And now with multiple races:

[Ranking on multiple races](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijny1.png)

With regards to the space and then repetition of the column titles, I have tried to create a new row like:

```
new_row = {
    "Title": "",
    "Distance": "",
    "Runners": "",
    "Age Group": "",
    "Class": "",
}

df2 = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

print(df2)
```

in a hope it would at least break the races up but it just adds a gap at the entire end of the df rather than at the end of each race. I have tried to play around with the placement of this and still no luck - it just adds it to the end.

With regards to the ranking I have tried to move around the df statements and include them in the for loop, after it etc to see if that changes it but no luck there - it still ranks the whole data frame rather than individual races.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting the values by odds, then grouping will ensure that they will be in the correct order once grouped.  Then converting to a `numpy` array and using `np.vstack()` to combine everything together:

Mock data (note that the column names are a bit different to your pictures, but that should be straightforward for you to change):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# mock data
horse_data = {
    'race_id': np.random.randint(1, 10, 100),
    'horse_id': [i for i in range(101, 201)],
    'horse_name': ['Horse '+chr(ord('A')+i) for i in np.random.randint(0, 26, 100)],
    'weight': np.random.randint(50, 65, 100),
    'age': np.random.randint(3, 7, 100),
    'odds': np.random.uniform(2, 5, 100).round(2)
}
df = pd.DataFrame(horse_data)
```

Combining output:

```py
# if adding rankings across all groups, add these here:
# df = df.assign(ranking_col=df["col"].rank(ascending=False))

# initial row
arr = np.zeros((1, len(df.columns)+1))  # +1 because 1 additional ranking column added in the loop.

# sort values by odds so in order and loop through each group (race id)
for i, j in df.sort_values("odds", ascending=False).groupby("race_id"):
    # add a ranking column
    j = j.assign(odds_ranking=j["odds"].rank(ascending=False))
    # additional rankings within each group/race:
    # j = j.assign(ranking_col_name=j["ranked_col"].rank(ascending=False))
    # append an row of 0s, then column names, then data to arr
    arr = np.vstack([arr, np.zeros((1, len(j.columns))),
                     np.array(j.columns), j.to_numpy()])

arr = arr[2:, :]  # drop first 2 rows
df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr)  # to DataFrame
# set the 0 columns to None so 'blank'
df1.loc[df1.eq(0).any(axis=1)] = None
```

If you then use `df1.to_clipboard(index=False, header=False)`, you can paste the output in Excel and see that there are blank rows and headers above each group.

Exporting to a `.csv`:

```py
df1.to_csv("racing_odds.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Unfortunately I am getting this error for the last "np.savetxt" line: line 31, in <module>
    np.savetxt("racing_odds.csv", df1.to_numpy(), delimiter=",")
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in savetxt
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1610, in savetxt
    raise TypeError("Mismatch between array dtype ('%s') and "
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e')

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I have changed it so that the code will now work.  The above is now `df1.to_csv("racing_odds.csv", index=False, header=False)`

Comment: thank you so much it works now. probably a dumb question but ive never used numpy - i presume i can just change your np.random.randint for my own value names and it would give the same result? i.e. 'horse_id': [i for i in range(101, 201)], would be "Horse": horse_name, still / just use my own DF instead of yours? As I also want to rank a few different things (odds, weight, official rating etc) can i just include them in without sorting the values, so outside of the "for i, j in df" loop or would i still need to have a "for item in df:" loop? thanks for your help again.

Comment: For additional rankings, if you want to rank across all races then put the code before the for loop; you can repeat the ranking line multiple times in the same place to rank different columns within each race.  Ranking does not sort the dataframe at all, so this will not change the order of the rows.

Comment: In your question, it looks like you have scraped a DataFrame already, so don't need to create new values.  But yes, you can add your own value names for your own testing in place of the `np.random.randint`, which was generating random integer values.

Comment: You may also need to change a few of the column names to match what you have.  `race_id` would become `Title`, `odds` would become `Exchange Back Odds`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much.or the multiple rankings do i just declare it as:
for i, j, k in df.sort_values("odds", ascending=True).groupby("race_id"):
     
    j = j.assign(odds_ranking=j["odds"].rank(ascending=False))

    k = k.assign(weight_ranking=k["weight"].rank(ascending=False))

and would I need to repeat this line for each of the rankings substituting out the letters for each rank:
    arr = np.vstack([arr, np.zeros((1, len(k.columns))),
                     np.array(k.columns), k.to_numpy()])

Comment: No, keep `j` as it is, this is the grouped dataframe.  You can use `j = j.assign(weight_ranking=j["weight"].rank(ascending=False))` to rank the weights in the group.  This will then add a column `weight_ranking` to the end of the dataframe, so you don't need to stack anything else.  In the initial creation of `arr`, before the loop, you will need to change `+1` to however many additional columns you are creating.

Comment: thank you so so much. it works a treat. very much appreciated.